# How to remove the widgets and replace them in python

Tags: python, windows, tkinter

i'm new to tkinter and wanted to change an already existing piece of code I made into GUI. The piece of code below is a username and password system. The thing I need help with is that I can not figure out how to get a new box or to remove the widgets of the gui. Nothing is wrong with the code below but I wanted to show you as it shows you how I've coded it and how to make a new box based on this code.
Btw I am in python 3.5.1 and on windows 10.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox as box
import time

def dialog1():
    username=entry1.get()
    password = entry2.get()
    if (username == 'Noel' and  password == 'Music quiz'):
        box.showinfo('info','You may now enter the Music quiz')
    else:
        box.showinfo('info','Invalid Login')



window = Tk()
window.title('Music quiz')
window.geometry("300x125")
window.wm_iconbitmap('Favicon.ico')

frame = Frame(window)

Label1 = Label(window,text = 'Username:')
Label1.pack()

entry1 = Entry()
entry1.pack()



Label2 = Label(window,text = 'Password: ')
Label2.pack()

entry2 = Entry()
entry2.pack()
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by 'a new box'

Comment: Basically what I want is to remove the widgets or the actual box that you made with the Username and password text, so I can do more GUI coding with it. It's a basic question but I'm an absolute noob at tinker so I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is edited code that I think will do what you have asked. Explanations are in the code in the form of comments.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox as box
import time

def dialog1():
    username=entry1.get()
    password = entry2.get()
    if (username == 'Noel' and  password == 'Music quiz'):
        box.showinfo('info','You may now enter the Music quiz')
        loginframe.destroy()  #remove the login frame
        ##code to create the quiz goes here##
    else:
        box.showinfo('info','Invalid Login')




window = Tk()
window.title('Music quiz')
window.geometry("300x125")
window.wm_iconbitmap('Favicon.ico')
loginframe = Frame(window)  #create an empty frame for login
loginframe.pack()  #put the empty frame into the window


#all elements below are put into the 'loginframe' Frame
Label1 = Label(loginframe,text = 'Username:')
Label1.pack()

entry1 = Entry(loginframe)
entry1.pack()

Label2 = Label(loginframe,text = 'Password: ')
Label2.pack()

entry2 = Entry(loginframe)
entry2.pack()

donebttn = Button(loginframe, text='Done',
                  command=dialog1)  #create a button to continue
donebttn.pack()  #display that button
mainloop()
```

Comment: That is exactly what I needed, it works and allows me to continue on coding my game. Thanks